# Time series classification using LSTM - How to approach?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, bigdata, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on an experiment with LSTM for time series classification and I have been going through several HOWTOs, but still, I am struggling with some very basic questions:

Is the main idea for learning the LSTM to take a same sample from every time series?

E.g. if I have time series `A (with samples a1,a2,a3,a4)`, `B(b1,b2,b3,b4)` and `C(c1,c2,c3,c4)`, then I will feed the LSTM with batches of `(a1,b1,c1)`, then `(a2,b2,c2)` etc.? Meaning that all time series needs to be of the same size/number of samples?

If so, can anynone more experienced be so kind and describe me very simply how to approach the whole process of learning the LSTM and creating the classifier?

My intention is to use TensorFlow, but I am still new to this.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is classification, then your data should be a a time series and a label. During training, you feed each into the lstm, and look only at the last output and backprop as necessary.

Judging from your question, you are probably confused about batching -- you can train multiple items at once. However, each item in the batch would get its own hidden state, and only the parameters of the layers are updated.

The time series in a single batch should be of the same length. You should terminate each sequence with a END token and pad items that are too short with a special token PAD  -- the lstm should learn that PAD's after and END are useless.

There is no need for different batches to have the same number of items, nor to have items of the same length.